# HAML syntax error "expecting $end"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, syntax-error

I am trying to DRY up some code in HAML, but seem to have stumbled into a whitespace error that I can't quite wrap my head around.

I took the header and left navigation code and put it into their own respective files in the `layouts` folder.

In the regular view files, I placed this at the top:

```
= render 'layouts/header'
  = render 'layouts/left_navigation'
  / center content column
  .centerContent.left.phm.rbm
    / start main center section
    / and the rest of the code goes below here
```

In the `header` file, I have:

```
/ main container area
#maincontainer
  / main content
  #maincontent.mhauto
```

And in the `left navigation` file, I have:

```
/ left navigation column
#leftNav.leftNav.left
  / a bunch of code goes in here
/ end left navigation column
```

Now, I would expect this to be equivalent to:

```
/ main container area
#maincontainer
  / main content
  #maincontent.mhauto
    / left navigation column
    #leftNav.leftNav.left
      / a bunch of code goes in here
    / end left navigation column
    / center content column
    .centerContent.left.phm.rbm
      / start main center section
      / and the rest of the code goes below here
```

But for whatever reason, it is not working correctly and instead gives me this syntax error `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end` while pointing to the last line in the file.  What am I doing wrong?  This is my first time using HAML, so this is rather perplexing to me.

By the way, it worked perfectly fine before I started DRYing up the code, so this seems to be a whitespace thing to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a render nested inside another render.. I think thats the problem:

```
= render 'layouts/header'
= render 'layouts/left_navigation'
/ center content column
.centerContent.left.phm.rbm
  / start main center section
  / and the rest of the code goes below here
```

Comment: But how would I tell HAML that I want `left navigation` to be nested within the header `#maincontent` tag without indenting the 2nd render?

Comment: If you want left_navigation within the header you just render it inside the header partial. If you dont want it to be render always then you should use a content_for :header